# PHP Oracle SQL Select date to_char

Tags: php, oracle, ora-00904

I am getting; `"Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "JAN": invalid identifier`", when I try to execute these commands:

```
function stime($conn3, $time){

    $result = oci_parse($conn3, "SELECT TO_CHAR($time, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM MON_EVENTS")or die(oci_error());
    oci_execute($result);
}
```

STIME is also a date field in the database.

I am passing the `STIME` field to `$time as stime($row_oci['STIME']).`

Comment: Can you check your date format?  Looks like you have a format wich contains `Jan` that must be `MON`in dateformat string

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why would you use a query to try to format the value of a PHP variable?

Comment: The query probably won't do what you are expecting: the result set will have one row per row of the `MON_EVENTS` table. All containing the _same_ value. Is there a confusion here between the `SELECT` and the  `WHERE` clause ?

Answer (score 2):

You were bitten by PHP [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation):

```
$result = oci_parse($conn3, "SELECT TO_CHAR($time, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM MON_EVENTS")or die(oci_error());
//                                          ^^^^^
```

`$time` is replaced by its content *converted to a string* -- and that *before* passing the value to the `oci_parse` function. As the string representation of a date might contain spaces, letters, `/`, ... it will confuse the Oracle SQL parser that report `ORA-00904: Invalid identifier`.

As of myself I would suggest to use bind parameter instead. This is much less error-prone -- and [much more safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Security_issues):

```
$result = oci_parse($conn3, "SELECT TO_CHAR(:time, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM MON_EVENTS");
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':time', $time);
```

Comment: Sylvain, thank you! This has gotten rid of the invalid identifier error. But it is still not echoing anything. When I return oci_bind_by_name($result, ':time', $stime); it just echo's 1.

Comment: I realised why it was returning 1. It was returning a match upon each row. I was not extracting the data from the array and echoing that. I solved the problem and put the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

$id = $row_oci['ID'];
$result = oci_parse($conn2, "SELECT TO_CHAR(STIME,'MON/DD/YY hh24:mm:ss') FROM MON_EVENTS WHERE ID = $id");
oci_execute($result);
while($row_result = oci_fetch_array($result)){
echo "". $row_result['0'] ."";}